# how to make flash movie as html link?

Tags: flash

How to make flash movie as html link?
E.g 
`<a>embed</a>`

its not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work in Actionscript 3

you need to use the navigateToURL() command which requires a URLRequest. Add a mouseclick event listener to the stage and in the function that is called in the event listener call the navigateToURL() command, passing the URLRequest of the url you want it to link to.

```
// add the click event listener to the stage
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);
//define the onClickHandler function to go to the url
  function onClickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void{
      navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com"));
    }
```

Comment: no i cant make link  in the flash file. There will be 1000 videos on my site. its not possible that i can edit each file. Can we make link to flash in html?

Comment: Oh ok well if there will be 1000 videos on your site then I assume there will have to be some sort of content management system at work here. If that assumption is correct then you can look into creating a template of html in your cms to hold your flash file if you are setting it up so it works in posts. then you can make the link in javascript and attach it to the div in the page template of the page that will hold your flash file.

Comment: if this is being built on wordpress for example: while in the wordpress loop, you could have something like: 
   <div onClick=window.location="http://someplace.com";or <?php  the_excerpt();(url) ?> >
    <?php the_content(); ?> (video post)
   </div>

something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

if you want to link a piece of flash to a web site simply in the .fla . Insert a new layer , name this layer a (for actionscript/actions) . Inside type the following, say the thing you wanted someone to click on was a button which you named ,as a movie clip * mcbutton *
:

```
mcbutton.onRelease = function:void () {
getURL("http://www.yahoo.com");
};
```